# Into and From interfaces: struggling with typing.Type's covariance

Tags: python, covariance, type-hinting

I'm trying to implement an interface for conversions between types but I'm struggling to make it consistent since `typing.Type` is covariant

```
U = TypeVar('U')


class Into(Protocol[U]):
    @abstractmethod
    def into(self, t: Type[U]) -> U:
        pass
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) give a similar example with a crucial difference

```
class User: ...
class BasicUser(User): ...
class ProUser(User): ...
class TeamUser(User): ...

def make_new_user(user_class: Type[User]) -> User:
    return user_class()
```

There they say type checkers should check that all subclasses of `User` should implement a constructor with a valid signature to be instantiated like this. My use case is different because I might not be constructing the new type, just returning a pre-existing one. Say I do

```
class X: pass

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, x: X):
        self._x = x

    def into(self, t: Type[X]) -> X:
        return self._x
```

that all works fine until someone subclasses `X`

```
w = Wrapper(X())
...
class XX(X): pass
x: XX = w.into(XX)
```

The RHS is fine by mypy cos `Type` is covariant, but clearly the API is broken cos an `X` isn't an `XX`. If `Type` wasn't covariant this wouldn't be a concern: the RHS wouldn't type check until `Wrapper` was updated to support `XX`.

My question is: Is there some way to achieve this (or something similar) given the covariance of `Type`?

**Context**

I want to use this to convert a type to multiple other types, specifying the desired type explicitly rather than just `into_X`, `into_Y` etc. I expect to do this with `TypeVar` or `overload`. I'm also having difficulty [there](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7701).

This is inspired by rust's `Into`, where `t: Type[U]` is a type parameter not a function argument.

Comment: `into` doesn't use its `t` argument at all, so inheritance or covariance isn't your issue.

Comment: @chepner I'd expect it to use the argument if I was implementing `Into[X]` and `Into[Y]` for a single class

Comment: that aside, can you elaborate on why not using the argument means covariance isn't the issue?

Comment: @joelb, can you present a simple use case of the code? I don't fully understand what you are doing. Is Wrapper supposed to extend the functionality of its input by adding a method into? What `Wrapper()` returns -- an instance of `Wrapper` or an instance of its input? Do you want to call `w.into(int)` and get the value stored in `w`, or do you want to modify `w` such that its attribute changes its type? Also, do you want to call `w.into(List[str])`, `w.into(List[int])` -- i.e., the same value converts to different types?

Comment: @joelb Because you aren't using `t`. Type checking aside, it doesn't matter *what* argument you pass, because `into` won't use it. Your type signature says "Give me a type, and I'll return an instance of that type (or maybe a subtype of it), but you never look at `t` to see what that type *is*; you just return `self._x`, which isn't related to `t` at all.

Comment: @chepner that's true, but what I imagine is that the types do that bit for me. If instead of `Type[X] -> X` I used a generic `Type[T] -> T` where e.g. `T = TypeVar('T', X, Y)` wouldn't the type that I pass in (`X` or `Y`) then define what the return type has to be (`X` or `Y` respectively)? And therefore the logic would have to be such that that is the case? The fact that we're not using `t` in this case is simply because it can't be anything _but_ `X` (or apparently some subclass of `X`)

Comment: @kate-melnykova this was inspired by attempting to convert between numpy arrays, tensorflow tensors and pandas dataframes. does that answer your qu?

Comment: @joelb, yes, thanks a lot. See the answer below.

Comment: @joelb It *hints* that the function should return an `X`, and a tool like `mypy` will raise an error if it detects you trying to return something, but the type hints have no effect at runtime: `into` can return anything at all.

Comment: @chepner I understand that. but I think this thread's getting a little long so I'll forgo further discussion here. Thanks for your points

Answer (score -2):

`eval` solves the issue.

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, x: X):
        self._x = x

    def into(self, t: Type[X]) -> X:
        return eval(f'{t}({self._x})')
```

Comment: You don't need `eval` at all; `return t(self._x)` would do the same thing (assuming `t` can be used to make a `t` out of `self._x`, or rather the result of `str(self._x)`, in the first place).

Comment: I assumed that `t` is a string.

Comment: `t` won't be a string. it's a type, e.g. if `self._x` is `1`, `t` would be `int`

Comment: My solution still works, the solution of @chepner is simpler and also works. I think that the question is resolved.

Comment: as chepner points out, this only works if you can construct an `X` out of another `X` like `X(x)`, which in general, you can't

Comment: It is impossible to write a general converter that can change the type of input to anything -- not all conversions have a unique way to be accomplished (list -> np.array) and not all conventions are possible (list -> integer). You can limit applicability to in-built types and a few other types. Just add `if issubclass(t, YourSpecialDataType)` to process other cases and include the inheritance.

Comment: This completely misses the point of the question.  This is about *static* type checking, not runtime behaviour.